# Android studio: "unfortunately, app has stopped"

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

---

i have no idea how this is not working. i checked all of the xml files i have created and the java files and there is no error in any of them as far as i know.

```
package com.example.jam7733.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class));
            }



                });}
        }
```

---

```
second java class for other activity 

package com.example.jam7733.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;



public class second extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

}
```

---

xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.jam7733.myapplication.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/initialappdesign">

<ImageButton
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:src="#fd0000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

also displays this which i really dont get

---

```
01-30 14:43:19.614 2730-2730/com.example.jam7733.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.jam7733.myapplication, PID: 2730
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jam7733.myapplication/com.example.jam7733.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
     at com.example.jam7733.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
     at com.example.jam7733.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
     at com.example.jam7733.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
  Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
     at com.example.jam7733.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

---

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jam7733.myapplication">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
                android:name=".second"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: have you seen that OutOfMemoryError? Are you loading some huge image?

Comment: Why do you have android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="horizontal" in a RelativeLayout?

Comment: I see an `OutOfMemoryError` there. Do you have any oversized images (74MB when uncompressed) in your app?

Comment: i do have a background image that is 1080x1920, but i removed it and ran it again and it still produced the same problem

Comment: Can you show us a manifest file?

Comment: To attract more attention to your post, I suggest you update the title of the question to something more descriptive like "App crashes when loading large image" because that seems to be the issues from those logs

Comment: i got rid of the image and it still crashes